# Use something other than externalinterface

Tags: flash, air, adobe, flex3

Created an application in Adobe, app was running fine in the browser. Decided to switch it to a Desktop app. But for some reason the ExternalInterface doesnt work in the desktop app. Any ideas on how to override this issue? Thanks!

Error:
The ExternalInterface is not available in this container....

Code:

```
private function logout(): void{
  modal.timeout.logout();
  ExternalInterface.call("logout");
}
```

Comment: As it seems, you need to translate the login/logout **JavaScript** functionality from that HTML page to AS3.

Comment: _" app was running fine in the browser"_ Have you tried simply opening your app/site `index.html` thru **stageWebView** and testing that it all runs ok?

Comment: @Organis Dont understand what you mean

Comment: @Karam The provided script makes a call to some (most probably **JavaScript** ) function called **logout()** that resides in the (head or body of the) **HTML** page. Once you switch to **AIR** application, you no longer have that **HTML** page, that means you need to copy that functionality (probably not only **logout** but **login** as well) and integrate it as a part of your **AIR** application. Calling **logout** without actual external environment to accept that call will not make you any good.

Comment: @Karam which is why to avoid recreating all these javascripts, just open the same app in browser anyway. That **stageWebView** is a browser engine, You don't recreate `google.com` page using AS3 code, instead you open the real `google.com` using **stageWebView** and type in their search box. If you don't want the built-in browser then go ahead and recreate the JS (or even PHP) login & logout functions from AS3 code alone.